# Ran into some troubles when using waypoints and jquery $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the latest waypoints library. Everytime waypoints passes a `program-block` it should log the value of the attribute `data-index` to the console but everytime this happens it outputs `undefinded`.

How can I handle this?

```
<div class="program-block" data-index="1"></div>
<div class="program-block" data-index="2"></div>
<div class="program-block" data-index="3"></div>
<div class="program-block" data-index="4"></div>
<div class="program-block" data-index="1"></div>

var waypoints = $('.program-block').waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log($(this).data('index'));
    }
});
```

[Here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/tbhdv1sg/) (but no working sample):

Here the [link](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to the waypoints website:

Comment: What exactly is not working? It logs something in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74rfao6f/1/)

Comment: Did you tried wrapping your code inside the `$(document).ready()`-handler?

Comment: Yes, with a version lower than 3 the demo works but I'm using waypoints v.3 in combination with sticky.min.js (also from the waypoints website) and I don't want to use two nearly similar libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Waypoints 3 `this` is not a reference to the HTML element. It is a reference to the Waypoint instance. To get to the underlying element, you must use `this.element`.